# Make a file open immediately after downloaded by user

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, onclick, download

Currently, I have a link to download a file on an HTML page.  If clicked on, it asks the user if the user is sure they would like to download the file, and after the user clicks on "yes" it downloads the file.  Is there a way to make it open the file immediately after the user says "yes"?

As things are the user has to go into their downloads folder and click on the downloaded file.  Then the computer asks the user if the user is sure they would like to open the file.  I'm just trying to eliminate these last two clicks to make things more convenient for the user.

Perhaps there's some kind of script I could run once the user decides they want to download the file?  I'm open to any approach you guys may have.

Comment: These clicks are there for a reason. Lots of malware over the years have prompted their existence there.

Comment: Short answer, no.  Long answer, what kind of file?

Comment: The internet would be a much more infected place if this were possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a security measure you cannot bypass, and is done for the client’s own security. There’s no way you can achieve this (well, perhaps on IE with an ActiveX control, but that won’t cover 100% of the cases).